# About diameter in a metric space.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

$\newcommand{\diam}{\operatorname{diam}}\newcommand{\cl}{\operatorname{cl}}$Let $(X,d)$ a metric space and $A \subseteq X$. Then $\diam(A)=\diam(\cl(A))$

I could prove $\diam(A) \leq \diam(\cl(A))$. Then I tried the following.

Let $x,y \in \cl(A)$, so $\forall \varepsilon >0$ $B_{\varepsilon}(x) \cap A \neq \varnothing$ and $B_\varepsilon (y) \cap A \neq \varnothing$ let $x_1$ an $y_1$ elements of the first and the second intersection respectively. Because the triangle inequality we have, $$ d(x,y) \leq d(x,x_1)+d(x_1,y) \leq d(x,x_1)+d(x_1,y_1)+ d(y_1,y)$$ We know that  $d(x,x_1) < \varepsilon ,\hspace{0.5cm} d(y,y_1) < \varepsilon$ and $d(x_1,y_1)<\diam(A)$ so $$d(x,y)< 2 \varepsilon+ \diam(A)$$ I think i did it well but i don't know how to conclude $d(x,y) \leq \diam(A) \hspace{0.3cm} \forall x,y \in \cl(A)$

Comment: Take a limit as $\varepsilon\to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

You got $d(x,y) < 2\epsilon + {\rm diam}(A)$ for every $x,y \in {\rm cl}(A)$ and every $\epsilon > 0$, good. Take the supremum over all $d(x,y)$ to obtain ${\rm diam}({\rm cl}(A)) \leq 2\epsilon +  {\rm diam}(A)$, for every $\epsilon > 0$. Make $\epsilon \to 0$ to obtain ${\rm diam}({\rm cl}(A)) \leq {\rm diam}(A)$.

Answer (score 0):

Then $$ \sup_{x,y\in cl(A)}d(x,y)\leq 2\varepsilon+ \text{diam}(A)$$
and thus it's finish.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon>0$, then there are $x',y' \in \bar{A}$ such that $d(x',y') > \operatorname {diam} \bar{A}- \epsilon$. Then there are $x,y \in A$ such that $d(x,x') < \epsilon, d(y,y') < \epsilon$. Hence $d(x',y') \le d(x,y) + 2 \epsilon$ and so
$\operatorname {diam} {A} \ge d(x,y) \ge \operatorname {diam} \bar{A}- 3\epsilon$.